# Copy images from folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of jpgs in one folder (images) that I want to copy across to another folder (destination_folder). When they are copied across, I want the jpg files to be renamed as follows: filename1_red.jpg, filename2_red.jpg (i.e. adding on the suffix _red at the end)

I have the following so far:

```
import os
images = os.listdir('C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../buses and motorcycles')
destination_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../Buses'

for img in images: 
    filename = os.path.basename(img)
    copyfile(img, os.path.join(destination_folder, filename))
```

Question 1: I get this error that I don't understand - how do I resolve it:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RWG074059_2_o.jpg'
```

Question 2: I am unsure how to get the suffix.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the question - how to add the suffix or how to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns just the file names of the files in the specified folder, it doesn't return the complete path to the file. So, you need to join the source folder path with `img`:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

source_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../buses and motorcycles'
destination_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../Buses'
images = os.listdir(source_folder)

for img in images:
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(img)
    filename = filename + '_red' + ext
    copyfile(os.path.join(source_folder, img), os.path.join(destination_folder, filename))
```

Comment: Thank you - appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

**How to debug this error:**

```
import os

directory = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../buses and motorcycles'
images = os.listdir(directory) 

for img in images: 
    print(img)
    filename = os.path.basename(img)
    print(filename)
```

Output:

```
main.py
main.py
```

**What you can see:**

You see that `listdir()` only returns *filenames*. You need to prepend the source folder again.

**How to fix:**

```
import os

directory = './'
destination_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../Buses'
images = os.listdir(directory) 

for img in images: 
    print(img)
    filename = os.path.basename(img)
    print(filename)

    # prepend path again
    source = os.path.join(directory,img)
    target = os.path.join(destination_folder,img)

    print(source, "=>",  target)

    # copyfile(source, target)
```

Output:

```
 ./main.py => C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../Buses/main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` only contains the name of the image, not the complete path information.

Build an aboslute path instead when you specify the source image:

```
import os
source_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../buses and motorcycles'
images = os.listdir(source_folder)
destination_folder = 'C:/Users/Admin-dsc/Documents/.../Buses'

for img in images: 
    filename = os.path.basename(img)
    copyfile(os.path.join(source_folder, img), os.path.join(destination_folder, filename))
```